# Signing amazon GetFederationToken in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I've got a piece of python code that requests a new federation token:

```
AWS_HOST = 'sts.amazonaws.com'
AWS_URI = '/'

AWS_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET = '...'

def amazon(content):
  URI_String=[]         
  for keyword, value in sorted(content.items()):  
    URI_String.append('%s=%s' % (keyword, urllib.quote(value)) 
  req =  '&'.join(URI_String)                                

  to_sign_req = 'GET\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (AWS_HOST, AWS_URI, req) 
  h = hmac.new(AWS_SECRET, to_sign_req, hashlib.sha256)      
  sig = base64.b64encode(h.digest())                         
  req += '&Signature=%s' % urllib.quote(sig)                 

  baseurl = 'https://sts.amazonaws.com?'                     

  apicall = baseurl + req                                    
  r = urllib.urlopen(apicall).read()                         
  return r
```

and I use it with such prepared content:

```
content['Timestamp'] = dstamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
content['SignatureVersion'] = '2'
content['AWSAccessKeyId'] = AWS_ID
content['DurationSeconds'] = '3600'
content['SignatureMethod']='HmacSHA256'
content['Version']='2011-06-15'
content['Action']='GetFederationToken'
content['Name']='someFederateduserName'
```

And it works fine. But when I try to add a policy ( `content['Policy']=POLICY` ), having POLICY =

```
{ 
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/foldername/*"
  }]
}
```

amazon returns `SignatureDoesNotMatch` response. Does anyone know how to fix it? I want to issue federation tokens with customized policies...

Comment: Okay, got it. `urllib.quote` leaves '/', so bucketname went wrong. adding `.replace('/','%2F')` fixed it.